# Mercury editor cannot save changes

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, editor, wysiwyg, mercury-editor

I'm using Mercury wysiwyg editor in my rails app ( https://github.com/jejacks0n/mercury.git,  8fd7f73029) and I can't handle it to save Article changes with an error 'Mercury was unable to save to the url'. Google console gives the following log:

```
ailed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)    http://localhost:3000/articles/3/mercury_update
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)    http://localhost:3000/articles/3/mercury_update
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)   http://localhost:3000/articles/3/mercury_update
PUT http://localhost:3000/articles/3/mercury_update 404 (Not Found) jquery-1.7.js:8158
```

**routes.rb**

```
mount Mercury::Engine => '/'
resources :articles do
 member { post :mercury_update }
end
```

**mercury.js** code inserted after *debug:false*,

```
onload: function() {
  //Mercury.PageEditor.prototype.iframeSrc = function(url) { return '/testing'; }
  Mercury.on('ready', function() {
    var link = $('#mercury_iframe').contents().find('#edit_link');
    Mercury.saveUrl = link.data('save-url');
    link.hide();
  });

  Mercury.on('saved', function() {
    window.location.href = window.location.href.replace(/\/editor\//i, '/');
  });
 },
```

**show.html.erb**

```
<span data-mercury="full" id="page_title"><%= raw @article.title %></span>
<div data-mercury="full" id="page_body"><%= raw @article.body %></div>

<%= link_to "Edit",  "/editor" + request.path, id: "edit_link", data: {save_url:   mercury_update_article_path(@article)} %>
```

**articles_controller.rb**

```
def mercury_update
  article = Article.find(params[:id])
  article.title = params[:content][:page_title][:value]
  article.body = params[:content][:page_body][:value]
  article.save!
  render text: ""
end
```

in layout file **mercury.html.erb** I have

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  // Set to the url that you want to save any given page to, leave null for default    handling.
  var saveUrl = null;

  // Instantiate the PageEditor
  new Mercury.PageEditor(saveUrl, {
    saveStyle:  'form', // 'form', or 'json' (default json)
    saveMethod: null, // 'PUT', or 'POST', (create, vs. update -- default PUT)
    visible:    true  // boolean - if the interface should start visible or not
  });
</script>
```

I tried everything, but nothing works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple typo - in layout i had conditional render of div id="page_title" so had two tags, and forget to include id="page_title" in the second case